# Is TextRenderer supported on CE?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Is TextRenderer supported on CE (.net compact edition)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Use [Graphics.DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/21kdfbzs(v=vs.100).aspx) instead.

TextRenderer is a workaround for a GDI+ flaw, CF doesn't use GDI+.

Answer (score 1):

I think Hans means: `Graphics.DrawString()`

Furthermore, you can take advantage of the `Drawing.StringFormat` class to get some of the functionality of `TextRenderer` in .NET CF.
For more info, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332kzs7c.aspx